# How to highlight the active state of the nav while scrolling?

Tags: jquery

I searching for a solution / function that is adding a class “active” to the navigation item once it’s clicked or if the page is scrolled to its particular section and also removing the class when you click on another menu item or scroll to a different section of the page. I came up with this:

```
    var listElement = $('#primary-navwrapper li');
    var offset = $('#header').outerHeight();



    listElement.find('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) { 
        // Prevent from default action to intitiate
        event.preventDefault();

        // The id of the section we want to go to.
        var anchorId = $(this).attr("href");

        // Our scroll target : the top position of the
        // section that has the id referenced by our href.
        var target = $(anchorId).offset().top - offset;
        //console.log(target);


        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target }, 500, function () {
            //window.location.hash = '!' + id;
            window.location.hash = anchorId;        
        });


    });
```

And this:

```
    function setActiveListElements(event){
        // Get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('#primary-navwrapper li a[href^="#"]').each(function() { 
            var anchorId = $(this);
            var target = $(anchorId.attr("href"));

// Here should be something, that is checking the position of the window or something, I think //

                    $('#primary-navwrapper li a').removeClass("current");
                    anchorId.addClass("current");
            }
        });
    }


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        //setActiveListElements();
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your sections are 100% height, then you can try using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) with the option `autoScrolling:false` as in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html)

Pay attention to how the menu gets updated on scroll. And it uses the `active` class for it.